# Installation warning or fail

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, updates

When i want to install nvidia-355 i get;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-355 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable
          Recommends: libcuda1-355 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: nvidia-opencl-icd-355 but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Whenever i want to update or install something i always get

```
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

any ideas to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since whichever of `apt`, `apt-get` or `other` you used successfully **Ignored** the file, one can infer that it did not **Use** the file.

Therefore, you can move it elsewhere for examination:

```
sudo mv --target-directory=/tmp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old
```

Or, simply delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old
```